# What does wave_read.readframes() return if there are multiple channels?

Tags: python, wave

I understand how the readframes() method works for mono audio input, however I don't know how it will work for stereo input. Would it give a tuple of two byte objects?

Answer (score 0):

A wave file has:

sample rate of `Wave_read.getframerate()` per second (e.g 44100 if from an audio CD).

sample width of `Wave_read.getsampwidth()` bytes (i.e 1 for 8-bit samples, 2 for 16-bit samples)

`Wave_read.getnchannels()` channels (typically 1 for mono, 2 for stereo)

Every time you do a Wave_read.getframes(N), you get `N * sample_width * n_channels bytes`.